# Android Strings issue

Tags: java, android, string, arraylist

My program produces a list of Strings in one activity, then passes it to another activity, and the second activity uses the strings.

When I test by printing out each element of the list at the beginning of the second activity, the printout looks perfect. For example, if I am hoping for the list to contain `"Lemon Juice"`, it prints out exactly right, but yet the logic in the second activity still doesn't work. If I add `"Lemon Juice"` just like that to the list manually, the logic in the second activity works fine, so the issue is that somehow the string in the received List is not really `"Lemon Juice"`. But:

1. It prints out exactly correctly (including checking for spaces in front and at the end).
2. I have tried explicitly casting the received list elements as (String) just to be sure they are Strings.
3. If I run `"Lemon Juice".contains(received String)` it comes back true, and if I run received `String.contains("Lemon Juice")` it
   comes back `true`, but if I run received `String.equals("Lemon Juice")` it comes back false.  This is very confusing to me.

Can anyone think of a possible explanation for how something that is cast as a string, prints as a string, and looks like a string, is not performing like a string?

EDIT to include some code as requested:

```
// instance variable at top of class--list to which strings will be added for use in
// 2nd activity
private List<String> exs = new ArrayList<String>();

// get array of strings from extra from intent from first activity
String[] recExs = getIntent().getStringArrayExtra(BrowseActivity.EXS);

for (int exx = 0; exx < recExs.length; exx++) {
String curEx = (String) recExs[exx];
    exs.add(curEx);
}
```

Somehow, when I pass exs to the method I need to use the strings, it doesn't work, even though, as explained above, printing and calling contains etc all show that the string, before I added it to exs, was at I wanted it to be.

Comment: Please post your code instead, a short snippet, relevant to your question. It's easier for us to help that way.

Comment: I only understood that you're fighting against strings...

Comment: Your cast to String is not needed there.

Comment: Could you post the code of the method that uses the strings?

Comment: what exactly doesn't work? if you got an array of strings, you have them just as you wanted them... btw you can use Arrays.asList instead of having the loop.

Comment: Now you know the `Strings[]` is passed correctly into the 2nd activity, so I'd check that the `List<String>` is still correct in the method that uses `exs`. If that list is fine it sounds to me more like a logic problem in this method.

Comment: Can you try to put a debug point in String class' equals method?
This would help you identify why exactly two strings are not matching

Comment: Show us how you add the String[] to the intent in the first activity. And also try exx <= recExs.length;

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to help when you only posted a small snippet of your code.

But I'm guessing the reason `String.contains` works but `String.equals` doesn't is that maybe there is space in the Strings. Try `String.trim` on both side of the Activity when passing and receiving data.